# ¿Cómo hacer una lista desplegable en un formulario symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2

Estoy intentando hacer una lista desplegable en mi formulario para que muestre las distintas opciones en un nuevo campo que no se encuentra en la base de datos ( es decir que solo se encuentre en el formulario ) y he usado este código:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fechaEvento')
            ->add('nombre')
            ->add('operarios')
            ->add('lista', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Evento',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->orderBy('e.nombre', 'ASC');
    },
            'choice_label' => 'nombre',));
    }
```

siguiendo esta [documentación](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) pero no consigo entender el funcionamiento y no lo muestra en mi formulario¿Algún posible error o no estoy entendiendo bien?
Gracias.

Añado la plantilla:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Evento creation</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('eventos_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: En la plantilla no se está renderizando ningún formulario. ¿Estás seguro que es la plantilla adecuada?

Comment: @Muriano perdon me he equivocado, ya muestra la lista ahora como edito los campos que esta contiene, es decir como los añado

Comment: Tendrás que ser más preciso. Quieres editar las opciones dentro del desplegable?

Comment: @Muriano eso es, que muestre en la lista los campos que yo quiera

Comment: En ese caso tendrás que usar un ChoiceType, te he actualizad mi respuesta para que lo veas mejor.

Comment: @Muriano muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu solución, funciona tal como queria!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa para ello la opción [mapped](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) y el tipo [ChoiceType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) esta manera:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
// ...


public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('fechaEvento')
        ->add('nombre')
        ->add('operarios')
        ->add('lista', ChoiceType::class,  array(
              'mapped' => false,
              'choices'  => array(
                  'Etiqueta1' => 'valor1',
                  'Etiqueta2' => 'valor2',
                  'Etiqueta2' => 'valor2',
              ));
}
```

Comment: No se si consigo entender el código, sigue sin mostrarme la lista, con los campos indicados, ni siquiera salta excepción ni nada

Comment: 'lista' es un campo de tipo "select" que no está en la base de datos como tal, no?

Comment: Exacto, lista es un campo que no se encuentra en la base de datos dado que no lo necesito, solo quiero mostrarlo en el formulario como indicación

Comment: Bien. Entonces el paso 1 es indicarle al formulario que no es un valor "mapeado" en la base de datos. Eso se hace con la opción `mapped` = false. Lo siguiente es ver cómo estás renderizando el formulario en la plantilla (considerando que el query_builder es correcto). ¿Podrías incluir esa parte del código en tu pregunta?

Comment: Actualizada, perdon por el fallo, te di la plantilla de index y queria pasar la de new

Comment: Usa en lugar del EntityType (que es para recoger los valores desde una table en base de datos) el ChoiceType. Este elemento te permite pasar una lista de valores en forma de array, donde la clave del array es la etiqueta del elemento generado, y el valor es el equivalente al value.